# Passing values from standard error function into a dataframe using a for loop

Tags: r

I am trying to pass a column of group standard errors into a dataframe which will eventually be used a long way down the road to make error bars.

First create data.

```
df <- data.frame(group = rep(c("group1", "group2", "group3", "group4"), 4), score1 = runif(16, 0, 10), score2 = runif(16, 3, 7))
```

Next create a function to calculate the group standard error.

```
groupSEs <- function (condGroup, colDV) {
  SE <- sd(df[df$group == condGroup, colDV])/sqrt(nrow(df[df$group == condGroup,]))
  return(SE)
}
```

Next create a vector of the group names

```
groupSubset <- c("group1", "group2", "group3", "group4")
```

Then make a data frame to pass the group standard errors into

```
SEFrame <- data.frame(SEs = rep(NA, 4))
```

Then create a loop that attempts (and fails) to pass each element of the group name vector through the SE function and into the dataframe.

```
for (setGroup in groupSubset) {
  sError <- groupSEs(setGroup, "score1")
  SEFrame[setGroup,1] <- sError 
}

View(SEFrame)
```

What gets spat out is this.

```
           SEs
1            NA
2            NA
3            NA
4            NA
group1 1.683297
group2 1.245539
group3 1.723762
group4 1.373125
```

What I really want is just the SE values alone pasted into the 'SEFrame' without: a) adding new rows to it; or b) adding the group names as row names. In other words like this:

```
       SEs
1 1.683297
2 1.245539
3 1.723762
4 1.373125
```

Any hints would be welcome.

Firstly to solve the problem above as it stands. I suspect it is an indexing problem in the for-loop.

Secondly to suggest a more efficient way of doing all this (aggregate or ddply maybe?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why you want this is a `data.frame` since it's just a 1d vector. But here you go

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(group = rep(c("group1", "group2", 
                               "group3", "group4"), 4), 
                 score1 = runif(16, 0, 10), 
                 score2 = runif(16, 3, 7))

groupSEs <- function (condGroup, colDV) 
  sd(df[df$group == condGroup, colDV]) /
  sqrt(nrow(df[df$group == condGroup,]))

groupSubset <- c("group1", "group2", "group3", "group4")

SE <- sapply(groupSubset, function(x) groupSEs(x, "score1"))

# if you want this is as a df
as.data.frame(SE, row.names=1:length(SE))

#         SE
# 1 1.237912
# 2 1.733068
# 3 1.584986
# 4 1.533830
```

Also, you just set a seed if you're going to generate random numbers, as I did.

Answer (score 1):

To fix the problem as it stands change the loop to:

```
for (setGroup in groupSubset) {
  sError <- groupSEs(setGroup, "score1")
  SEFrame[grep(setGroup, groupSubset), 1] <- sError 
}
```

and here is a way to do it with `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(reshape2)

SEFrame <- df %>%
  melt(id = "group") %>%
  group_by(group, variable) %>%
  summarise(
    SE = sd(value) / sqrt(n())
  )
```

Comment: ``apply`` is generally preferred over ``for`` in R. also using ``grep`` is a bad idea since you are pattern matching. But if you're going to use this approach than ``for (i in 1:length(setGroup)) SEFrame[i, 1] <- groupSEs(setGroup[i], "score1")`` would be better.

Comment: @nathanesau those are good points.  i was mainly just trying to fix the loop as it stands.

Comment: Thankyou @feats-by-jake. Very helpful on both counts. I am a little confused though. Can you explain to me why using SEFrame[grep(setGroup, groupSubset), 1] in the second line of the loop meant the SE calculated for each group passed straight into the dataframe whereas when I used SEFrame[setGroup,1] it created new rows?

Comment: @llewmills Please up vote if you like the answer.  `grep(setGroup, groupSubset)` is returning the position of `setGroup` in `groupSubset`.  For example, `grep("group1", groupSubset)` returns 1 so that the group 1 standard error is placed in `SEFrame[1, 1]`.  The way you had written it the standard error was placed in `SEFrame["group1", 1]` which is why the code was adding rows to `SEFrame`.

Comment: thank you again @feats-by-jake. I tried to up vote but I can't until i've earnt 15 points of reputation. Sorry. You've been really helpful.